# Tomar un valor de select de una función que carga en documento ready

Tags: jquery, select

En el documento ready cargo una función ajax que me rellena un select, lo que necesito es poder desde el document ready tomar el primer valor que genera ese select.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    responsable(); //FUncion que me rellena el select (ajax)
    valor= $("#respPrsp").val(); //Aqui quiero tomar el valor del select
 }); 


function responsable(){ //Función que uso para pedidos.

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/PlnDir/respPed.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            objJsonResp = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(objJsonResp, function (j, item) {
                $('#respPrsp').append("<option value= " + objJsonResp[j]["resp"] + " >" + " " + objJsonResp[j]["resp.name"] + "</option>");
            });
        }
    }); 

}
```

El problema es que valor me sale Null, como si lo tomara antes de que cargara la funcion.

Answer (score 0):

Puede estar pasando lo que tu comentas, que lo ejecutas antes de que llegue. Prueba a añadir la siguiente línea:

```
$("#respPrsp").change(function(){
valor= $("#respPrsp").val();
});
```

Comment: Buenas, si, cuando lo hago en ese evento si me toma el valor, el problema es que yo necesito usar ese valor en el document ready, al cargar la pagina. No me vale si el usuario tiene que actuar sobre el select

Comment: Necesitas trabajar con un valor de un select, el cual nadie ha seleccionado? No acabo de entender tu necesidad.

Comment: por defecto el select tiene un valor aunque no haya sido seleccionado, despues cuando seleccionas otro llama a la funcion pasandole el valor pero al principio, necesito que me tome el valor que tenga por defecto.

Comment: En la vista, ese valor se muestra en el select?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que a la hora de cargar tu `Select` no hay ninguna opción seleccionada, el `value`de tu `Select` solo cambiará cuando se seleccione una opción, si quieres que una aparezca seleccionada por default, puedes añadirle el atributo `selected` cuando cargas las opciones, de la siguiente manera:

```
$.each(objJsonResp, function (j, item) {

            if(j===1){

                $('#respPrsp').append("<option value= " + objJsonResp[j]["resp"] + " 
                 selected>" + 
                " " + objJsonResp[j]["resp.name"] + "</option>");


            }
            $('#respPrsp').append("<option value= " + objJsonResp[j]["resp"] + " >" + 
            " " + objJsonResp[j]["resp.name"] + "</option>");

 });
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.